# Can't get my cursive font to connect fluidly (FontForge)

Tags: fonts, kerning, font-forge

I've made a cursive, Arabic-esque font in FontForge and everything works great, but the letters don't quite connect right, there's almost always a little gap.

I've tried messing with kerning and spacing both in the program and externally but nothing seems to work :/

[image: FontErrorExample]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe solution is as simple as to set bearings left or right or both. Are your glyphs  with correct directions?  All clockwise.